# Relationship between Fourier transform and matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, matrix-exponential

Let's assume we have (in vector form)

$$\dot x(t) = A x(t)+L w(t)$$

The solution to this general linear time-invariant non-homogeneous ODE, with null boundary values, can be written as

$$x(t) = \int^t_{0} \exp\{A(t-\tau)\} L w(\tau) \ d \tau$$

The book I'm reading, when solving the original ODE, with a Fourier Transform, writes the solutions as the convolution:

$$x(t) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(t-\tau)L w(\tau) \ d\tau$$
where $f(t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[((i\omega)I - A)^{-1}\right]$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier Transform.

From what I understood, the author states that comparing this solution, to the previous stated solution, we can deduce $f$ to be equal to $\exp\{At\} H(t)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function.

My doubt is that we have the lower bound of the integral with convolution as zero, due to the presence of the Heaviside function. However, what guarantees that the upper bound of the integral will also be $t$? The convolution is integrated along the whole of real numbers.

Comment: What is the book/page?

Comment: You actually have it turned around. You are integrating $f(t - \tau) = e^{A(t-\tau)}H(t-\tau)$. It is when $\tau > t$ that $H(t - \tau) = 0$, which takes care of the *upper* bound. I think the author may be getting the lower bound from the "null boundary value" condition. I.e, if you are not concerned about the behavior for $t < 0$, you can just assume that $w(t) = 0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for your comment. One remaining doubt, though... Wouldn't that assumption on $w(t)$ have implications on the continuity of $w$, and on certain theorems that ensure existence of solutions, etc.?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What do you mean by natural response?

Comment: Nevermind. I was looking for initial conditions, which you called boundary conditions. With zero initial state, the natural response is zero.

Comment: I am interpreting "null boundary values" to mean $w(0) = 0$, so setting $w(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$ doesn't break continuity.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks ;)

Comment: Actually, it is more broad than that. If they are only trying the solve the problem for $t \ge 0$, then any theorems you are talking about only need to apply to $t \in [0,\infty)$, where $w$ would be continuous in any case (right-continuity at $0$ is all that is needed), so it doesn't matter how $w$ behaves $< 0$. And as for the convolution, if it couldn't handle a jump-discontinuity, we couldn't put the Heaviside function in it either.